# UnsupportedDependencyException when running my spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I run my spring application, I get an UnsupportedDependencyException even though I autowired my beans and defined my applications.properties.

Exception:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field laptopRepository in com.microcenter.service.LaptopServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.microcenter.repository.LaptopRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.microcenter.repository.LaptopRepository' in your configuration.

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'laptopApi': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'laptopService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'laptopService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'laptopRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.microcenter.repository.LaptopRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.microcenter.MicroCenterApplication.main(MicroCenterApplication.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'laptopService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'laptopRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.microcenter.repository.LaptopRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.microcenter.repository.LaptopRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1717)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    ... 33 more
```

Main class:

```
package com.microcenter;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MicroCenterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SpringApplication.run(MicroCenterApplication.class, args);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

API Class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/laptops")
public class LaptopApi
{
    @Autowired
    private LaptopService laptopService;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<List<LaptopDTO>>  getLaptops()
    {
        List<LaptopDTO> laptops = laptopService.getLaptops();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(laptops, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Repository Class:

```
package com.microcenter.repository;

import com.microcenter.entity.Laptop;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface LaptopRepository  extends CrudRepository<Laptop, Integer>
{
}
```

I have autowired all the necessary beans, however, it says that it can't find the required bean. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: You excluded auto-configuration for the datasource. Please could you add your @Configuration ?

Comment: application.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/laptop_db
spring.datasource.username=root
#spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa-show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

server.port=8080

Comment: some pieces are missing here. can you share your project on git or at https://tmpfiles.org/? I will try to run this at my side.

Answer (score 0):

add class level annotation for LaptopRepository ex: @Repository ... so that application context can create bean object for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the DataSource yourself or remove the exclusion of DataSourceAutoConfiguration. Without datasource, the repository is not created.

```
// 1) remove the annotation, Spring will configure the datasource
//@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})

// 2) configure by youself if you need
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-a-datasource)

Comment: I managed to get it to work without the datasource annotation. The trick is in application.properties.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is in "application.properties", where you need to specify the datasource credentials.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/laptop_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port=8765
```